# Redirect Standard Output of CreateProcessWithTokenW in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I have an app that launches another process.

The first app is launch in admin and the second in the desktop user. 
Before this need, I was launching the process with basic C# handle

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = string.Format("{0}\\program.exe", lcb.Client.InstallDirectory);
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

And after I was handling the standard and error output in my main application.

But now I launch my process like this

```
var res = RunAsDesktopUser(fileName, arguments);
var process = Process.GetProcessById(res.dwProcessId);
```

And inside RunAsUserDesktop I use the winapi method in advapi32.dll CreateProcessWithTokenW.
I then get the process back like intended but when after I try to read the Standard output I got an exception saying that the process is not started or the standard output is not redirected.
So I must probably do something to redirect the standard output

This method takes some argument like this struct

```
private struct STARTUPINFO
{ 
    public Int32 cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public Int32 dwX;
    public Int32 dwY;
    public Int32 dwXSize;
    public Int32 dwYSize;
    public Int32 dwXCountChars;
    public Int32 dwYCountChars;
    public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
    public Int32 dwFlags;
    public Int16 wShowWindow;
    public Int16 cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}
```

I kinda understand I must set the hStdOutput and hStdError IntPtr to something but I don't get what. And I can't find any documentation of this Anyone knows how to work around this?

Comment: The 3 Streams you redireect are properties of Process, not part of the StartInfos.

Comment: I look at startInfos cause in the old code it was here the magic happend p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
If you have any advice to make me redirect the 3 steam i would appreciate it.

Comment: You'll need a [lot more pinvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

Comment: @HansPassant there is a lot of code i will try to check on this but sadly all time this kind of code are in cpp and i can't include the same.h in C# and some type like HANDLE don't exist in C# i don't know how to "translate it"

Comment: @Jebik I think this whole thing started because you tried to start a process with lower rights then the one you are running. That does not work. | You have two options: a) Hardcode/Configure a specific user account including password to use b) Start your Application as user. Elevate only the programm that needs it. Everyone has to bite that bullet and pick b eventually.

Comment: @ChristopherI don't think i have much a choice.

I launch an app in multiple client. That need admin right to workproperly change desktop shortcut for public user ect... then when the app finish an update it must launch the updated service. But with the windows user. not with admin right... 
I can't ask permission every time i need to make and update cause it production server nobody is connected to it to accept it.. 

But that true i maybe go the wrong way but i don't find any simplier way to achive what i need

Answer (score 2):

Create a pipe, and redirect the child process' stdhandle to the write side of the pipe (or directly to the stdhandle of the parent process).

The following method redirects the stdhandle of the subprocess through the pipe.
(BTW: You can declare type of `HANDLE` as `IntPtr`)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IntPtr out_read;
        private static IntPtr out_write;
        private static IntPtr err_read;
        private static IntPtr err_write;
        private static int CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;
        private static int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
        private static int BUFSIZE = 4096;
        private static int HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT = 0x00000001;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            saAttr.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
            saAttr.bInheritHandle = 0x1;
            saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;

            CreatePipe(ref out_read,ref out_write,ref saAttr, 0);
            CreatePipe(ref err_read, ref err_write,ref saAttr, 0);

            SetHandleInformation(out_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
            SetHandleInformation(err_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
            PROCESS_INFORMATION res;
            RunAsDesktopUser("C:\\test.exe",out res);
            byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
            int dwRead = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                bool bSuccess = ReadFile(out_read, buf, BUFSIZE, ref dwRead, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0)
                    break;
                Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buf));
            }
            CloseHandle(out_read);
            CloseHandle(err_read);
            CloseHandle(out_write);
            CloseHandle(err_write);
        }

        private static void RunAsDesktopUser(string fileName, out PROCESS_INFORMATION pi)
        {
            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(fileName));

            // To start process as shell user you will need to carry out these steps:
            // 1. Enable the SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in your current token
            // 2. Get an HWND representing the desktop shell (GetShellWindow)
            // 3. Get the Process ID(PID) of the process associated with that window(GetWindowThreadProcessId)
            // 4. Open that process(OpenProcess)
            // 5. Get the access token from that process (OpenProcessToken)
            // 6. Make a primary token with that token(DuplicateTokenEx)
            // 7. Start the new process with that primary token(CreateProcessWithTokenW)

            var hProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            // Enable SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in this process.  (This won't work if current process is not elevated.)
            try
            {
                var process = GetCurrentProcess();
                if (!OpenProcessToken(process, 0x0020, ref hProcessToken))
                    return;

                var tkp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
                {
                    PrivilegeCount = 2,
                    Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[2]
                };

                if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", ref tkp.Privileges[0].Luid))
                    return;
                if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeImpersonatePrivilege", ref tkp.Privileges[1].Luid))
                    return;

                tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0x00000002;
                tkp.Privileges[1].Attributes = 0x00000002;

                if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcessToken, false, ref tkp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                    return;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
            }

            // Get an HWND representing the desktop shell.
            // CAVEATS:  This will fail if the shell is not running (crashed or terminated), or the default shell has been
            // replaced with a custom shell.  This also won't return what you probably want if Explorer has been terminated and
            // restarted elevated.
            var hwnd = GetShellWindow();
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            var hShellProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
            var hShellProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            var hPrimaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                // Get the PID of the desktop shell process.
                uint dwPID;
                if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out dwPID) == 0)
                    return;

                // Open the desktop shell process in order to query it (get the token)
                hShellProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, false, dwPID);
                if (hShellProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return;

                // Get the process token of the desktop shell.
                if (!OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, 0x0002, ref hShellProcessToken))
                    return;

                var dwTokenRights = 395U;

                // Duplicate the shell's process token to get a primary token.
                // Based on experimentation, this is the minimal set of rights required for CreateProcessWithTokenW (contrary to current documentation).
                if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hShellProcessToken, dwTokenRights, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out hPrimaryToken))
                    return;

                // Start the target process with the new token.
                si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO));
                si.hStdOutput = out_write;
                si.hStdError = err_write;
                si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
                if (!CreateProcessWithTokenW(hPrimaryToken, 0, fileName, "", CREATE_NO_WINDOW, IntPtr.Zero, Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), ref si, out pi))
                    return;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hShellProcessToken);
                CloseHandle(hPrimaryToken);
                CloseHandle(hShellProcess);
            }
            return;
        }

        #region Interop


        private struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        {
            public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
            public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        private struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public LUID Luid;
            public UInt32 Attributes;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
        {
            All = 0x001F0FFF,
            Terminate = 0x00000001,
            CreateThread = 0x00000002,
            VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
            VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
            VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
            DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
            CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
            SetQuota = 0x00000100,
            SetInformation = 0x00000200,
            QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
            QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
            Synchronize = 0x00100000
        }

        private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
        {
            SecurityAnonymous,
            SecurityIdentification,
            SecurityImpersonation,
            SecurityDelegation
        }

        private enum TOKEN_TYPE
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }
        private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public Int32 nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref LUID pluid);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint processId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreatePipe(ref IntPtr hReadPipe, ref IntPtr hWritePipe, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes,Int32 nSize);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, byte[] lpBuffer, int nNumberOfBytesToRead, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped/*IntPtr.Zero*/);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetHandleInformation(IntPtr hObject, int dwMask, int dwFlags);


        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, uint dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpTokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL impersonationLevel, TOKEN_TYPE tokenType, out IntPtr phNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(IntPtr hToken, int dwLogonFlags, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The 3 Streams (most people do not know about Error) are part of the process class, not StartInfo. Those bools merely define if they can be be "taken out" of their normal place. Otherwise the getter will throw a Exception.

Here is the example code for one of them:

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
    ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("net ", "use " + args[0]);

    myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
    myProcess.Start();

    StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardError;
    // Read the standard error of net.exe and write it on to console.
    Console.WriteLine(myStreamReader.ReadLine());
}
```

This pattern (Property protected by a bool switch) is a somewhat rare pattern. I saw it a few times with rather old code (BackgroundWorker comes to mind), but it seems to have fallen out of favor.

Comment: I understand this but as i say in my post it was working fine when i was creating my process with this code 
But now i create the process with some windows api method and the process is already start when i get it back into C#
And i can't set the start info to redirect the standard output this way

Comment: @Jebik: To my knowledge you use either the Windows API or Process - wich wraps around that API - not both.